# Overriding configuration files of composer packages in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a Lumen project with external Composer packages installed. As usual with Lumen, they're stored in the `vendor` directory, each in their respective folder. Some of these packages have configuration files, which I would like to override with custom ones.

I have registered the files in my `bootstrap/app.php` using `$app->configure()` right after I register the application itself, so it looks like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . '/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/../')
);

$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();

$app->configure('/Configuration/Lumen/app.php');
$app->configure('/Configuration/Lumen/auth.php');
$app->configure('/Configuration/Tymon/jwt.php');
```

The files are present in their respective directories, and contain the settings I want Lumen to use instead of the defaults, which are located, respectively, at:

```
/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/app.php
/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/auth.php
/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/config/config.php
```

The problem I run into is that with this configuration, Lumen seems to ignore my custom files, and instead uses the defaults. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't there a equivalent of `php artisan publish` in Lumen? In laravel you can publish all kinds of config with this, which Laravel then autoloads.

Comment: Run `php artisan vendor:publish` to generate config files inside your config folder for these packages which you can override.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. I ended up having to install a third party package, though, as Lumen seems to be stripped of "vendor". https://github.com/laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your configuration files in `config/` and register them in `bootstrap/app.php` by their filename, without the `.php` file ending.

```php
// Your custom config in config/jwt-auth.php
$app->configure('jwt-auth');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the above answers is truly answering what the OP wanted to know how to do.

What they appear to want, is to load a composer package and register that packages configuration into the app without having to do any kind of manual configuration.

Sort of like when you import a standard composer package which builds a logger using environment variables and autoconfigures its setup without having to add that configuration to the app. So then things are simpler.

Although I'm assuming the OP knows that this leads to a few problems, in that you're stuck with a composer package configuring your app, with a few options to override those settings locally.

But I assume you're happy with that. So therefore, I'd like to propose this solution

In your composer package, create a `providers` folder, then add this code into a lumen service provider class, in my case I've called it `TestProvider`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourLibrary\Providers;

class TestProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Because we're using 'require', this needs to be a valid path
        $path = __DIR__.'/vendor_config.php';
        
        // Get a configuration object from the service container
        $config = app()->make('config');
        
        // An example: Set into the 'app' configuration at a specific subkey
        // just to show you can modify the default app configuration
        $config->set('app.subkey', require $path);
        error_log(json_encode(config('app')));

        // An example: Set into the 'vendor.test' configuration at a specific subkey
        $config->set('vendor.test', require $path);
        error_log(json_encode(config('vendor')));

    }
}
```

As you can see, you can use the dot notation for the first parameter to set() to insert your configuration into the applications config, but be careful with the naming cause in theory I guess you could override any setting like this, it could be that you end up overwriting the entire `config('app')` and all it's settings which would lead to a partially non-functioning app.

Then inside your `bootstrap.php` file in your app, you need to register this service provider, like so:

```
$app->register(YourLibrary\Providers\TestProvider::class);
```

I've tested it with an app I was working on locally and this works and I'm already using it for a library that has a very static configuration, everything is working pretty great.